# AntD - Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using antD for my project and today I attempted to update from 4.12.x to the latest version 4.21.7 and I started getting the below error

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I'm on react 17.0.1

Here's a code snippet that was working just fine

```
useEffect(() => {
  setDataSourceDraft(() => {
    return dataSource;
    
  });
}, [dataSource, dataSourceDraft]);
```

Also I had to replace

```
let inputRef = useRef<Input>(null);
```

with

```
let inputRef = useRef<InputRef>(null);
```

since the new update

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the state of a variable included in a dependency array inside of the same useEffect will result in infinite renders unless there is some condition to the updating of the state, which you do not have stated. Try removing "dataSourceDraft" from your dependency array, and see if that solves the issue. This may break another part of your code, but without seeing the rest it is difficult to provide a comprehensive solution.

In short, useEffect will run the function passed as the first parameter any time any of the variables in the dependency array change. In your case, it's looping because dataSourceDraft changes, which runs the useEffect, which modifies the dataSourceDraft, which runs the useEffect, and so on.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
useEffect(() => {
  setDataSourceDraft(() => {
    return dataSource;
  });
}, [dataSource]);
```

Comment: I have to keep the array because that’s how the page rerenders if the table got edited, react will not detect changes if I remove the array from the dependency. It was working with a previous version of ant design and once I updated the library it stopped working and on GitHub seems like everyone is having the same issue starting from version 4.17.x+